# segmentation fault on a recursive function

Tags: c++, g++

I simply want to test something. I am wondering what I did wrong?

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   unsigned long pwr(unsigned long n, unsigned long m)
   {
          if(m == 0)
            n = 1;
          if(m == 1)
            n = n;
          n = pwr(n, m/2) * pwr(n, m/2);
          return n;
   }

   int main ()
   {
          unsigned long n(2), m(16);
          cout << pwr(n, m);
          return 0;
   }
```

output is

```
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Have you tried printf debugging to see on what line it fails and how deeply it's recursed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no exit from recursion.

You may wanted

```
          if(m == 0)
             n = 1;
          else if(m == 1)
             n = n;
          else 
             n = pwr(n, m/2) * pwr(n, m/2);
          return n;
```

Answer (score 3):

Infinite recursion: The recursive call is executed unconditionally, and so the call stack grows until an error stops it.

This is a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You're not ending the recursion when you hit your base case.  Even when `m == 0` or `m == 1` are true, you still recursively call `pwr`.  So you've got infinite recursion.

Answer (score -1):

you are dividing by 0: let's say m starts from 1, in the next iteration m = 1/2 = 0, and you will get the fault.
what you probably want to do it return 1 if m = 0 instead of going through the method.

Comment: `m` is never used as a divisor, only `2` is.

Comment: that is not a base since you continue running the method. you need to return something at that point to stop the recursion.