# segfault due to finite recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, valgrind

I'm receiving a segfault which I believe to be caused by a large number of recursive calls. This has been noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202445/segmentation-fault-on-a-recursive-function). My confusion is that the recursion is not infinite; there is a definite breaking point once a given event occurs and that event will always occur, eventually. I suspect the issue is that the number of recursive calls before breaking is too many. Output from valgrind:

```
==903368== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==903368==
==903368== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==903368==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFE801FF8
==903368== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==903368==    at 0x4081B4: operator-(Point const&, Point const&) (Point.h:47)
==903368==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==903368==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==903368==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==903368==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==903368==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==903368== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==903368==
==903368== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==903368==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFE801FE8
==903368== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==903368==    at 0x482F14D: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:57)
==903368==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==903368==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==903368==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==903368==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==903368==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==903368==
==903368== HEAP SUMMARY:
==903368==     in use at exit: 86,717 bytes in 40 blocks
==903368==   total heap usage: 52,536 allocs, 52,496 frees, 47,716,014 bytes allocated
==903368==
==903368== LEAK SUMMARY:
==903368==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==903368==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==903368==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==903368==    still reachable: 86,717 bytes in 40 blocks
==903368==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==903368== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==903368==
==903368== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==903368== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Attempt to reproduce:

```
void f(int i, const int& niter) {
    i++;
    if (i < niter)
        f(i, niter);
    else 
        return;
}

int main()
{
    // fine
    f(0, 1000);
    
    // not fine
    f(0, 1000000);
    return 0;
}
```

Should I be increasing the main stack size as suggested by valgrind? Or just avoid the recursion altogether?

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000) 
        i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you possibly reduce the size of activation record?  Otherwise, changing stack size seems to be the best bet.

Comment: All resources in any computer are finite. What method to use to efficiently solve a problem depends on the problem and circumstances. You have apparently hidden the actual code and problem, so it is impossible to give definite advice. Most likely you should avoid recursion. It is rarely a good solution outside of computer science classes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil not entirely correct, Recursion is good when it does what is required effeciently and smoothly, take a look at Tower of Hanoi, or BST recursive, or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euclidean-algorithms-basic-and-extended/.

Comment: @YunfeiChen -- The `geeksforgeeks` site is notorious for poor, buggy, code examples.  If you're learning how to program from that site, there are much better options.

Comment: @YunfeiChen -- In addition, the `gcd` that you linked to is implemented in [std::gcd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) using a `while` loop, not recursion.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but you can remove that `else return;`. It doesn’t do anything.

Comment: @YunfeiChen: Tower of Hanoi, the Euclidean algorithms, and insert and search algorithms for binary search trees are readily written as iterative algorithms, and implementing them with recursion is wasteful, not efficient.

Comment: @algae: Nothing internal to the program “thinks” something is infinite. The error occurs because a finite resource has been exceeded by a use that is, at the moment of error, finite but larger than the available resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each level of recursion takes up a certain amount of memory on the stack. On all platforms I'm aware of stacks have a fixed (but configurable) relatively small size.

Ultimately the number of recursions is limited to `(stack size) / (stack used per call)` so to increase the number of recursions you need to either increase the size of the stack or decrease the size required for each call. In your example you appear to have an 8mb stack so to achieve 1,000,000 levels of recursion each level can only allocate 8 bytes on the stack which is probably not possible in most implementations.

One way to decrease the size of each call is to pass a reference to a structure containing any static parameters rather than individual parameters. In your example case this won't help as you only have one static parameter. What might help on platforms where an `int` is smaller than a pointer (e.g. most 64-bit platforms) would be to remove the `const&` as the reference is likely to be passed as a pointer.

If the above doesn't work then recursion should be replaceable with a non-recursive implementation and store your state in a `std::stack` which is heap allocated and won't therefore cause stack overflows.

Answer (score 3):

You should change the function to be non-recursive. In most modern architectures (including x86) recursion is implemented on the stack and the stack is limited: it is relatively small and does not grow as needed. As such you should avoid recursive functions as a rule of thumb because they have the known issue of starving the stack.

Recursion may seem like the perfect match for a problem, but that is just the way you as a human think about the algorithm. However every recursive function can relatively easily be transformed to a non-recursive function holding the step state in a dynamic structure like `std::stack`. Also a lot of recursive algorithm have at least a known non-recursive equivalent algorithm.

So I encourage you to transform the function into a non-recursive one and to avoid recursive functions altogether (outside of learning exercises)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mention recursion is expensive and you should go iterative way.. However in your case if you have a bit of knowledge about math you can make you problem very very efficient....

Simply put you can store you last value inside a variable like so:

```
int last = 1000;
```

and then do the following:

```
int total = (last + 1)*last /2;
```

So this makes your algorithm O(1);